# Fetch data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

There is a get request in `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
   var manufacturers = []

   this.props.participants.map(participant => {
     Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, "").then(result => {
      manufacturers.push(result)
      console.log(manufacturers)
    });
  });

  this.setState({
    participants: manufacturers
  })
}
```

This `console.log(manufacturers)` shows that there are objects in the array, but the state of component is empty. How to set it properly after fetching data?

Code of `Get()` function:

```
const Config = require('Config')
export async function Get(type, userData) {
    let BaseURL = Config.serverUrl;
    let result = {};
    if(userData)
        result = await fetch(BaseURL+type, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + userData,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
        });
    else
        result = await fetch(BaseURL+type, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        });
    let data = await result.json();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple `Get` calls to be made and each one is `async`, you will have to wait until all the result is `collected` and then set it to the state. You can do it by using `Promise.all` which can `wait` for all the `Get` calls to be resolved first, and then set the data to the state.

I would first create an `async` function and call it in `componentDidMount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchAllData();
}
```

Then inside this method, wait for all `Promises` to be resolved and set it to the state once we have the data. you might have to wrap the whole function inside a `try..catch` block so that if there is any promise rejection due to failure of network call, you can handle it appropriately.

```
fetchAllData = async () => {
  const manufacturers = await Promise.all(
    this.props.participants.map(participant => 
      Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, ""))
  )
  this.setState(manufacturers)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setState in Get promise callback

```
componentDidMount() {
   var manufacturers = []

   this.props.participants.map(participant => {
     Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, "").then(result => {
      manufacturers.push(result)
      console.log(manufacturers)
      this.setState({
        participants: manufacturers
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your this.setState inside of the .then. Don't exactly know why you're pushing the data to the manufacturers array first. If you use that array for something. If you already have the result in the state you probably won't need the manufacturers array. If not .. You can just set the state with the result like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
   var manufacturers = []

   this.props.participants.map(participant => {
     Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, "").then(result => {
      manufacturers.push(result) // Do you need this?
      console.log(manufacturers)
        this.setState({
          participants: result
        })
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from async logic. Using `this.setState()` outside of the fetch's `then()` causes the `manufacturers` property to be empty.

What is complex in your case is that you need to resolve multiple queries in parallel before updating the state. This can be made using the `Promise.all()` function :

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.all(this.props.participants.map(participant =>
    Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, "")
  ).then(results => {
    this.setState({
      participants: results // or results.map(result => result.data()) ...
    })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the state before the `ComponentDidMount` method is called:

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { participants:null }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always update State in 'then' or catch block of promise when promise is resolved/rejected...like below

```
componentDidMount() {
var manufacturers = []

this.props.participants.map(participant => {
 Get("manufacturer/" + participant.id, "").then(result => {
  manufacturers.push(result);

   this.setState({participants: manufacturers});
   console.log(manufacturers);

  });
 });
}
```

Since your get function returns promise which is async call, when get function executes, it skips to next line of code before resolving to this.setState() in your case, hence not showing updated state.
Always remember setState() itself is async and if u need to do any operation after setState , do it in setState() 's callback optional argument like:-

```
this.setState((currentState)=>{
 // you can access the currentState here
 },()=>{
 //your callback... here you can access directly this.state since it is guranteed 
  //that it will be updated state always
});
```